# OrchardCMS Content Permissions

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.9

We have built an application using OrchardCMS version 1.9.2.0

I am struggling to find the right way to set permissions. We have created some custom roles and assigned some new users to these roles using the standard Orchard Users module.

We also have the Orchard.ContentPermissions - Version: 1.6 installed for setting permissions on items.

It seems like the base Orchard permissions take priority over the content permissions.

E.g. if i don't set the View Page permissions under the Page heading within a role (https://db.tt/2kgHtalc), i get a message saying ...

*Cannot view content. Current user, [username], does not have ViewContent permission.*

Even if i have set permissions for that role on individual pages (https://db.tt/BnS3uzWK).

The issue is that if i add the View Page permission to the role, all pages seem to inherit the permission and the user can view everything. Again, regardless of the settings on each individual page.

Basically, what i want to be able to do is set individual permissions for individual pages. Is that possible? Seems pretty basic! So i think i am missing something.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve this one by reinstalling the module. Not sure what caused the problem in the first place.

As a note: when you uninstall the module, the table...

[CF_Orchard_ContentPermissions_ContentPermissionsPartRecord]

doesn't get removed. So reinstalling the module works but enabling tries to create a table of the same name which causes an SQL error. The error log mentions that this table still exists.

Delete the table and try to enable again and you should be good.